# Nothing happened when trying to add new vm on virt-manager

Tags: libvirt, arch-linux, virt-manager, kde

I try to create new vm or see connection details
with virt-manager but nothing append, no popup, no error message, nothing.

see here:
[image: https://imgur.com/ngkJhud]

i click but nothing append
i use arch with kde
libvirtd is enable and my user is on group kvm and libvirt

virsh works fine

when i run `virt-manager --debug` and clicking i have this error:

```
[sam., 22 juin 2019 12:26:56 virt-manager 9274] DEBUG (cli:197) Uncaught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/manager.py", line 469, in show_host
    from .host import vmmHost
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/host.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .hostnets import vmmHostNets
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/hostnets.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .createnet import vmmCreateNetwork
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createnet.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .xmleditor import vmmXMLEditor
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/xmleditor.py", line 6, in <module>
    gi.require_version('GtkSource', '4')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 129, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace GtkSource not available
```

after some research i found that https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62960
and installing gtksourceview4 package seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug. Try running 'virt-manager --debug' from a terminal, and see if you get a backtrace when clicking the 'New VM' button

Comment: thanks, with the --debug i found the bug and find how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 (devel) i also had to install gir1.2-gtksource-4, beside the packages libgtksourceview-4-0 and libgtksourceview-4-common.